# How can I interact with irregular elements using Python/Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using a page that has out of the ordinary elements.  Some of which are buttons that cannot be clicked using an xpath, link text, or id locator.

Here is the html for one button.

`<div class="goog-inline-block goog-custom-button-inner-box">Save &amp; Go Back</div>`

How should I go about including these kinds of buttons and objects in my script?

Comment: What other information do you need?  I just have no way of interacting with the web element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a CSS selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.goog-inline-block.goog-custom-button-inner-box").click()
```

Comment: This worked!  I did driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.goog-inline-block.goog-custom-button-inner-box")[1].  Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

I would say use the class, but it has a compound class name so I don't think that will work.  Ask the developer to put an ID on the button.